# Merge two variables into one date variable

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a dataset with six variables. The first and second variables are date variables:

- `var1` is date in format `dd/mm/yyyy`
- `var2` is time in format `hh:mm:ss`

How can I merge this two variables in one correct date-variable?

Here an example of the dataset:

```
> IVE_tickbidask[1,]
          V1       V2    V3   V4    V5  V6
1 09/28/2009 09:30:00 50.79 50.7 50.79 100
```

Comment: This is off topic for [stats.se] as the question is about using the R langauge, not about statistics. [so] would be a better home, but please wait to see if a mod can migrate this to the other site alongwith the answer you received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste` to combine both strings and `strptime` to generate a time object.

```
IVE_tickbidask <- transform(IVE_tickbidask, 
                            time = strptime(paste(V1, V2), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

str(IVE_tickbidask)

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ V1  : Factor w/ 1 level "09/28/2009": 1
 $ V2  : Factor w/ 1 level "09:30:00": 1
 $ V3  : num 50.8
 $ V4  : num 50.7
 $ V5  : num 50.8
 $ V6  : int 100
 $ time: POSIXct, format: "2009-09-28 09:30:00"
```